# How to check GPS availability every 1 sec in android using coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-gps

I am working on a project that needs to request data based on location. so after checking permission before I start requesting location data I want to check if the user's Gps is on or off. I just know how to do it with a handler. But is there any way to do the below code in kotlin coroutines?

```
private fun isGpsAvailable() {


    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    val runnable  = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val manager :LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !manager.isProviderEnabled(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Gps is not available") 
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }else{
                foregroundOnlyLocationService?.subscribeToLocationUpdates()
                    ?: Log.d(TAG, "Service Not Bound")
            }
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a location listener and set the update duration to anything you want
I guess you can not get each 1 sec

Comment: I know how to get the location. I just want to know how to use coroutines instead of Handler

Comment: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html This link could help you.